# How to insert parameters from external config file into Spinnaker pipeline?

Tags: spinnaker

On Spinnaker UI, I could see in the Pipelines Configuration stage, there is a section called “Parameters” wherein I can specify parameters to be used in the subsequent stages.

However, instead of manually hand configuring parameters one-by-one from Spinnaker UI, is it possible to have some stage in Spinnaker pipeline read these parameters from an external file or from a file on GitHub repository?

[image]

Comment: Spinnaker pipelines are json and you can edit / create it as JSON

Answer (score 0):

As @Mickey Donald mentioned all Spinnaker pipelines are just JSON files.

You can use consul-template to generate or set the values for those parameters by retrieving them from a Consul instance.

Another approach is to generate a JSON file with Terraform, later in reference and import the file using Jsonnet into your pipeline to generate a new one with the values already populated.

Whatever you method you decide to use, you’ll end up needed a new Spinnaker pipeline with a Save artifact stage to load the new pipeline into Spinnaker or use the spin cli to load it via GitHub Actions, Jenkins, etc…